# How can I redirect based on referrer

Tags: javascript, redirect

I'm really new to javascript, I've been experimenting and I've been enjoying as well.

I want to try and redirect people to this page if they did not come from this referrer and not redirect if they were.

But I have a problem, the problem is the referrer link CHANGES DYNAMICALLY, so I can javascript to only check if it was from this main link and ignore other parts.

For example.

I want them to come from google.com generally. But the only way google can refer them to my site is through a dynamic link, say google.com/323asda2 and that code changes every time the link is accessed.

Right now here's my code :

```
<script>
if (document.referrer !== "/^https?:\/\/([^\/]+\.)?google\.com(\/|$)/i") 
{
    alert("** This is a message from the website administration ** \n\n In order for this site to be safe we use bot checker captchas. You will be redirected to our captcha page and you'll be able to access the website after filling that in.")
    window.location.href = "http://websitename.com";       
}
</script>
```

And when they try to access the page from google, the loop goes on and on because the link (later part; google.com/323asda2 >323asda2) changes dynamically.

Basically I want the script to only check for the main link, not other parts of it

I hope you understood my question and I hope you can help me out!

Comment: Java and Javascript are entirely different languages. Don't tag a Javascript question with Java (at best it has no effect, at worst you'll get negative feedback/downvotes). I've removed that Java tag for you.

Comment: Yup, sorry about that as well, as said I was new to this whole thing. :)

Comment: Instead of trying to match the entire referrer, save it inside a variable and check if the string contains the url: `var ref = document.referrer; if(ref.search(/^https?:\/\/([^\/]+\.)?google\.com(\/|$)/i)){ // alert here }`

Comment: Thank you very much icecub! This has been exactly what I've been looking for. I can't upvote you answer since it's a comment but kudos!

Comment: I've turned it into an anwer. It's not like I'm asking for the upvote, but it allowes you to close your question :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to match the entire referrer, save it inside a variable and check if the string contains the url:

```
var ref = document.referrer;

if(ref.search(/^https?:\/\/([^\/]+\.)?google\.com(\/|$)/i)){
    // alert here
}
```